# Rails i18n ActiveModel: Translate error message for absence validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, localization, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have this validation in a service class:

```
class Users::Updater
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates(:frozen_identification_data, absence: { message: 'Identification fields cannot be changed at this time' } )
end
```

I'm trying to move this error message into a locales file:

```
en:
  activemodel:
    errors:
      users/updater:
        attributes:
          frozen_identification_data:
            absence: "Identification fields cannot be changed at this time"
```

But when I reproduce the test case, the error message is `Frozen identification data must be blank`. I'm assuming `absence` is incorrect here, but I can't find any examples of this usage on Google. Does anyone know how to translate this validation?

Comment: Instead of `absence` try `present` once as the key

Comment: @Deepesh that worked. If you make this an answer, I will upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From rails guides: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation

For `absence` the key should be `present`:

```
en:
  activemodel:
    errors:
      users/updater:
        attributes:
          frozen_identification_data:
            present: "Identification fields cannot be changed at this time"
```